# Prevent TextInput to focus while scrolling on iOS

Tags: ios, react-native

I have a `ScrollView` with a `TextInput multiline={true}` field which serves as a text area with dynamic height, and content read from state (it has a `Text` field inside which displays the text).

My problem is that when the `TextInput` grows to a couple of lines, if I scroll the screen by swiping over this field (I don't long press or anything like that), the field will fire its `onFocus` event and the keyboard will show.

It doesn't happen every time but it happens enough times to make it super annoying.

I tried setting `ScrollView` to `keyboardDismissMode="on-drag"` but it doesn't help, the keyboard still shows while the view is scrolling.

```
<ScrollView keyboardDismissMode="on-drag">
  <TextInput multiline={true} onFocus={() => console.log('boop')}>
    <Text>{this.state.someText}</Text>
  </TextInput>
</ScrollView>
```

I also tried doing it without the `Text` field inside `TextInput` and `onFocus` still fires up.

Am I doing something wrong? Is there anything else I could try, like checking if the screen is still scrolling and `blur()` the field if `true` or something like that?

Is there any way I can only focus the field if I 'explicitly' tap on it?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I have the same problem

Comment: Same here, still trying to figure this out. Trying out responders.

Comment: @rudikovac I think I figured it out, answer coming soon.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a *hacky* workaround:

Wrap your `TextInput` in a `TouchableOpacity`, and set the `TextInput`'s `pointerEvents` prop to point to a state variable, i.e. `this.state.pointerEvents`, and initialize the variable to `'none'`. This stops the `TextInput` from receiving any touch events, and lets you swipe over the top of it without capturing focus.

In the `onPress` prop of the `TouchableOpacity`, enable the `pointerEvents` by setting your state variable to `'auto'` and then manually assign focus using a reference to your `TextInput`, i.e:

`this._textInput.focus()`

Finally, override the `onBlur` prop of your `TextInput` and have it reinitialise the `pointerEvents` state back to `'none'` so it behaves just like before after the user has finished editing.

**Explanation**

The way this works is that the `TouchableOpacity` essentially captures all of the touch events that would normally be consumed by the `TextInput`, but interacts with drags along the rest of your UI in the friendly way we'd expect it to. When the `onPress` event is fired for the `TouchableOpacity`, we really are talking about a genuine press event, and not a misrecognised drag.

If you'd prefer not to use `TouchableOpacity`'s animation, you can assign the `activeOpacity` prop to `1`, or use a `TouchableWithoutFeedback` instead.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Working again in 0.54.2!

You should conditionally exclude this code on Android (as was done below), since this seems to have been taken care of by React Native now.

---

**Update**

No longer works in 0.49.0

---

Wrap your `TextInput` in a `View` with the proper `panHandlers`. Here's a component that will do just that:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Platform, PanResponder, View, TextInput as RNTextInput} from 'react-native';

class TextInput extends Component<Props> {

  componentWillMount() {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
      this.panResponder = PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponderCapture: () => true,
      });
    }
  }

  render() {
    <View {...Platform.OS === 'ios' ? this.panResponder.panHandlers : {}}>
      <RNTextInput {...this.props} />
    </View>
  }
}
```

Tested in RN 0.46.1.

Comment: It works great, but it also blocks the onBlur event and the tap-to-close-keyboard outside the TextInput for me

Comment: @Alex does this still happen with RN >= 0.54.0?

Comment: Yeah, I've got this issue right now @Palisand and I'm using 0.55.4. I just want it to stop focusing my inputs when I'm trying to scroll!

Comment: Fortunately, there's something else you can try! I suggest using it alongside the changes I presented above: set https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/2e384184bc7b3173e3bb41e2128eb75ba8aee8db/Libraries/Text/TextInput/Multiline/RCTMultilineTextInputView.m#L34 to NO (will require rebuilding)

Comment: The above answer is the one that absolutely nailed it for me, appreciate the help though.